# in gae, is number of write operations taken to write a single entity and core values same or not?

Tags: google-app-engine

What is difference between storing 10 entities separately and storing 10 entities as core values(ie, Lists or Sets) in google appengine datastore?

Are both taking same number of write operations or storing lists reduce the write operations count?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look with the new Cloud Monitoring service, see https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs; among other things it can show you graphs of RPC delays encountered by your app.

Different app-side "bridges" to storage may have different behavior; for example, `ndb` (for Python apps) strives "behind the curtains" to transparently use caching on your behalf, and "bunch up" RPC calls to the datastore (it also lets you do the latter explicitly with `_multi` and `_async` methods and functions).  In other languages, or if using the old `db` in Python, you may observe different performance characteristics on the app side because they may employ such optimizations to different extents, all the way to "none at all".

At the lowest abstraction level, however, "bunched" and "async" behavior will always have a performance advantage versus writing each entity singly and synchronously.

If the back-end of the datastore gets fewer RPC calls each requesting substantial amounts of writes, it can organize its own operations better than if it gets many RPC calls each about writing a single entity

The "async" behavior doesn't affect that (except that it may let `ndb` do more "bundling" behind the curtains) at the lowest abstraction level (the datastore back-end must do the same amount of work whether the app side is blocked waiting for the results, or just has a `future` watching asynchronously) but it can still improve your app's performance as things can "overlap" and your app is able to do something else before waiting for the `future` to deliver.

So each "bridge" should document exactly what it's doing on your behalf, but even if it does things are complex enough (esp. in a multi-instance, multi-threaded app) that it's worth experimenting and using Cloud Monitoring to check the actual performance effects of different approaches.